# XAMARIN how to add jar to my project

Tags: android, jar, import, xamarin

i'm working in xamarin. I have simple class where i need use class IOUtils. It's in:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

How can i import this jar to my project file?

I'm using vs2012.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a [binding library](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/) for it.

Comment: can we any external library in xamarin like sliding menu ??